# Value of type 'UIView?' has no member 'titleLabel'

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, uibutton, admob

I am trying to specify custom font for admob native ads CTA button.

But I'm getting this error.

> Value of type 'UIView?' has no member 'titleLabel'

ListTileNativeAdFactory:

```
class ListTileNativeAdFactory : FLTNativeAdFactory {

...

...

  (nativeAdView.callToActionView as? UIButton)?.setTitle(nativeAd.callToAction, for: .normal)
  nativeAdView.callToActionView.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 20)//This line gives error! 

...
...

  return nativeAdView

  }
```

How can I solve my problem? Thanks...

Comment: `callToActionView` is a `UIView?`. Optionals have no properties (of any interest), and even if you unwrap it, you just have a UIView — and a UIView has no `titleLabel`. You need to _downcast_ this thing to a UIButton (if you believe it is a UIButton). You did that in the previous line, and there's a reason why you had to do that. That same reason didn't magically go away.

Comment: so what is code solution?

Comment: I'm not going to write your code for you; I'm trying to _teach_ you something. Think about what I've said; everything you need to know is there.

Comment: What should I write to Google?, It is UIButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. We need **NSAttributedString** & **NSMutableAttributedString** classes.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring

For nativeAdView, don't use **setTitle** method, instead use

**setAttributedTitle** method.

As a result,

**The solution:**

```
class ListTileNativeAdFactory : FLTNativeAdFactory {

...

...

  let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 20.0)! ]
  let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: nativeAd.callToAction!, attributes: myAttribute)
  (nativeAdView.callToActionView as? UIButton)?.setAttributedTitle(myString, for: .normal)

...
...

  return nativeAdView

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to repeat what you did on the line above: `(nativeAdView.callToActionView as? UIButton)?`. Or wrap these two lines in a `if` clause

```
if let callToActionButton = nativeAdView.callToActionView as? UIButton {
    callToActionButton.setTitle ...
    ...
}
```